# RTK Query: undefined extraOptions inside prepareHeaders

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I set `extraOptions` in my endpoint like so :

```js
const myApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: builder => ({
      changePassowrd: builder.mutation({
          query: (data) => ({
              url: `${Config.BASE_URL}/users/${data.userId}`,
              method: 'PATCH',
              body: data,
          }),
          extraOptions: () => ({
            myOption: 'Test Option',
          }),
      }),
  })
})
```

And I try to read `extraOptions` in `prepareHeaders` like so:

```js
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: Config.BASE_URL,
  prepareHeaders: (headers, {getState, extra}) => {

    console.log('Extra Stuff', extra); // undefined

    return headers;
  },
});
```

But I'm always getting **undefined** in the console after triggering the mutation, why is that? Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's `redux-thunk`'s `extra`, not the endpoint's `extraOptions`. It seems like `fetchBaseQuery` generally does not make use of `extraOption` -  a pull request integrating that where necessary is highly welcome.